# Is it possible to run a stored procedure using sqlcmd and save the output into an Excel or .csv file?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

I have a stored procedure which outputs 2 tables. I would like to save the output into two `.csv` files or into one Excel file. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: which version of SQL Server you are using.

Comment: sql server 2008 R2

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how much it can help you, but you can create a DLL to generate CSV by excepting some input data and use that dll inside extended stored procedure. Call that store procedure using [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-2017).

[Extended stored procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/extended-stored-procedures-programming/adding-an-extended-stored-procedure-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

But be aware Microsoft is suggesting to not use extended stored procedure as it will not be available in future.

> Important
>
> This feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server. Do not use this feature in new development work, and modify applications that currently use this feature as soon as possible. Use CLR Integration instead.